# How to prevent a disorderly adding of controls using GWT?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I use GWT in my application to create two panels with the same button. For example there are two classes for two panels PanelFirst and PanelSecond  and a class for a button MyButton which shows alert after clicking. I add a button to both panels and expect to see a page with two panels with the same button on each panel. But I get two panels where  PanelFirst is empty and PanelSecond have two overlapped buttons (button looks like one button and when I click it I get two alerts and in DevTool in html I see two buttons placed in the same place). Why this is happening?  Is the root cause in asynchronous js? And how can I solve this issue?

To understand me better I attach an example of code (It's not a real code. It's just common sample).

```
class PanelFirst {

   private static Button myFirstButton = new Button();
   private static FlowPanel firstPanel;

   public PanelFirst (){};

   public FlowPanel createPanelFirst(){
     firstPanel = new FlowPanel();
     myFirstButton = MyButton().createMyButton();
     firstPanel.add(myFirstButton);
     return firstPanel;
   }   
}

class PanelSecond  {

   private static Button mySecondButton = new Button();
   private static FlowPanel secondPanel;

   public PanelSecond(){};

   public FlowPanel createPanelSecond(){
     secondPanel= new FlowPanel();
     mySecondButton = MyButton().createMyButton();
     secondPanel.add(mySecondButton);
     return secondPanel;
   }   
}

class MyButton {

   private static Button mySecondButton = new Button();

   public MyButton(){};

   public Button createMyButton(){
     mySecondButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                createAlert("I'm button");
            }
        });
     return mySecondButton;
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you are basically adding the same button 2 times to the 2 panels and adding 2 `ClickHandler`'s to it. You need to change your code like this:

first change your `createMyButton` to a static method and create a new object there

```
class MyButton {

    public MyButton(){};

    public static Button createMyButton(){
        MyButton button = new MyButton();
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                createAlert("I'm button");
            }
        });
        return button;
    }   
}
```

now you can use it in your panels:

```
class PanelFirst {

    private static FlowPanel firstPanel;

    public PanelFirst (){};

    public FlowPanel createPanelFirst(){
        firstPanel = new FlowPanel();
        firstPanel.add(MyButton.createMyButton());
        return firstPanel;
    }   
}

class PanelSecond  {
    private static FlowPanel secondPanel;

    public PanelSecond(){};

    public FlowPanel createPanelSecond(){
        secondPanel= new FlowPanel();
        secondPanel.add(MyButton.createMyButton());
        return secondPanel;
    }   
}
```